# want to set the time to capture the video using GSTREAMER

Tags: c, ubuntu, gstreamer

> gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src   ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mp4mux !
>   splitmuxsink max-size-time=30000000000 location=test1.mp4

This is my pipeline when I'm executing this it gives error like this

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "splitmuxsink"

any solution for this WARNING. I installed every plugins and I am beginner to gstreamer.

Give me some idea to set time of capturing the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

splitmuxsink sink was added in gstreamer version 1.6, make sure you have 1.6/+ (**gst-launch-1.0 --version** should tell you which version is installed), also its part of gst-plugins-good make sure you have installed it. Adding a [link](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html) for your reference to install gstreamer on linux machines.

> gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mp4mux !
>   splitmuxsink max-size-time=30000000000 location=test1.mp4

Also your above pipeline is wrong it should something like below,

> gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src num-buffers=500 !
>   video/x-raw,width=320,height=240 ! videoconvert ! queue ! timeoverlay
>   ! x264enc key-int-max=10 ! h264parse ! splitmuxsink
>   location=video%02d.mov max-size-time=10000000000
>   max-size-bytes=1000000

Refer [splitmuxsink](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-splitmuxsink.html), it adds the muxer for you.

Comment: Thank you lemme check and let you know